# Idea Intellij: automatically Maven generated artifacts vs manually created artifacts - only the auto works (screenshots)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I try to get a hang of deploying web apps using Idea Intellij. I have a simple app with an `index.jsp` and a servlet and a `pom.xml` file. I tried to approaches to make it work (meaning, when I click a Run tomcat button a can view start page and servlet page).

The first approach is `Create new project` in Idea's start menu. Then I would choose Maven project. After that, having set up the project files, when I go to `Edit configurations` and create `Tomcat`, when I click `Fix it` in the artifacts section, there are already `.war` and `.war exploded` artifacts waiting to be picked:

**Auto-generated artifacts**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, when I open an existing project and try to create artifacts on my own, I can't quite get the same result (only one war is generated, even if I try to create the second - war exploded - it wouldn't appear as a sub-war of the first war and the design would look different):

**Artifacts, generated by hand**:

[image]

To make matters worse, only the first approach (auto generated wars when creating a new Maven project) works. The second doesn't and I can't view the index or servlet page (404 error) and the folder `GameArchive` inside `tomcat/webapps` representing the artifact only has `META-INF` folder, with `WEB-INF` being absent.

How to I manually create artifacts in the same way Idea generates those when creating a new Maven project?

Comment: Is it possible to share existing project?

Comment: @y.bedrov What do you mean?

Comment: Is it possible to provide project example where artifacts aren't created?